# Why does Pass-the-ticket work?

Tags: security, encryption, authentication, kerberos

So, I've been informing myself about how Kerberos works and what attacks can be launched/defended against. One vulnerability I have read about is the "Pass-the-ticket" attack, when for example a domain admin leaves behind a Ticket Graning Ticket on a compromised User machine, that can be dumped/recovered (via mimikatz?). I do grasp the concept, I just don't understand *why* this method works. Now my question is: What good is a domain admins' TGT to the attacker? Or any users' TGT? As far as I understand,

- the **TGT** is encrypted with the **TGS' secret key** (which the attacker doesn't have), and you can not use it to access ressources, only to request a Service ticket from the TGS
- The **Service Ticket** is returned to the client along with an authenticator message, which contains the **Service Session Key** which the Client needs to communicate successfully with the requested Service
- This message is however encrypted with the **TGS Session Key**, that is only known to:

  1. the original/legitimate client in the AS-REP step,
  2. the TGS (contained in the TGT (which is encrytped))

  Meaning, the attacker cannot decrypt the message and therefore can't obtain the Service Session Key. Without the Service Session Key contained in this message, the attacker should not be able to access the resource offered by the Service, so even though he could find a TGT, and through that get a Service Ticket, he should not be able to access anything since he's missing the Service Session Key that the Service uses for encrypting data.

I'm sure I got something confused here, but an answer to such a specific question is difficult to research, so I would be glad If someone here could educate me about this topic :D

PS: For terminology clarity, I am referring to this youtube video explaining Kerberos : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N242XcKAsM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding stealing tickets using Mimikatz:

Your Kerberos ticket cache generally stores both the ticket *and* the corresponding session key in the same place, **and the term 'ticket' is often used as shorthand for both.** (In other words, the credential cache *necessarily* stores all information that a legitimate program needs in order to use those tickets.)

For example, in the [file-based ccache](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/formats/ccache_file_format.html) format used by Unix software (MIT Krb5, Heimdal, Java) each record has a `keyblock` field which contains the session key for the `ticket` that follows. This means that if you steal someone's `/tmp/krb5cc_UID` file, you now have both the TGT itself and the TGT's session key – which allows you to request more tickets (or renew TGTs) and decrypt their service session keys.

Similarly on Windows, the LSA internal `_KERB_TICKET_CACHE_ENTRY` structure ([as seen by Mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/blob/master/mimikatz/modules/sekurlsa/packages/kuhl_m_sekurlsa_kerberos.h#L492-L525)) contains a `SessionKey` field next to every `Ticket`, so if you dump it you get everything you need to impersonate the user.

---

Regarding connections to untrusted machines:

Normally, when you (let's say as a domain admin) connect to a service and authenticate using Kerberos, the server only receives your ticket for that specific service (the TGT is never sent except to KDCs), and it only receives a one-time authenticator but of course not the session key. So your credentials remain secure even if the network and/or the server are untrusted.

But connecting to a machine **over RDP** is slightly different than connecting to most other kerberized services, as it *by default* transfers (delegates) your credentials to the remote machine – the RDP client sends not only the 'TERMSRV' service ticket, but also transfers your whole TGT *and* its accompanying session key.

This is deliberately done so that after logging in via RDP you would be able to actually *do* things, e.g. access file shares – but of course it results in storing your TGT (and its session key) within the untrusted remote machine's LSA or /tmp where it can be dumped without your knowledge.

It is possible to disable RDP's credential delegation using "Restricted Admin" mode but it will result in some functionality not being available on the remote machine.

(SSH and PSRemoting also support delegation for the same reasons, but they do not enable it by default. For example, `ssh -K` would cause the service to receive your full TGT.)

Comment: Thank you for that thourough explanation, I think I understand it now. Not only do I dump the TGT, but also the corresponding session key to successfully impersonate the User Authenticator message with it - after all, the session key has to be stored locally on the machine as well along with the TGT, so both can be read by Mimikatz.
So, I guess that means domain admin accounts should rather not be used to log into User Workstations if it's not necessary to mitigate the risk of pass-the-ticket attacks?

Comment: @Washbear: Yes, you should use a normal non-DA account for daily work – have a GPO that grants e.g. the "IT staff" group _local_ admin rights on user machines, don't rely on DAs automatically being local admins... (In fact the general recommendation is to avoid using DA even for _your own_ workstation.) But even if you don't use DA accounts, additional mitigations are still a good idea, as even local admin is still valuable. If you're RDP'ing, then "Remote Credential Guard" will probably give you the best of both worlds, without any of the downsides that Restricted Admin would have.

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[Pass the ticket](https://www.thehacker.recipes/ad/movement/kerberos/ptt)
which explains the attack.

Briefly, the request for accessing a service, called Service Ticket (ST),
contains enough information about the user to allow the
destination service to decide to grant access or not, without asking
external players. This information is stored in a protected blob inside
the ST called PAC (Privilege Attribute Certificate).
In theory, the user requesting access can't tamper with that PAC.

More information stored in the ST outside of the PAC, and is unprotected,
called `sname`, indicating which service the ticket is for.
This information is basically the SPN (Service Principal Name) of the
target service.

It's split into two elements: the service class, and the hostname.
There are multiple service classes for multiple service types
(LDAP, CIFS, HTTP and so on).

The problem here is that since the SPN is not protected, there are
scenarios where the service class can
be modified in the ticket, allowing attackers to have access to
other services.

In that way, the attacker can use the
original credentials to access other services to whom the original
user had the right to access.

For this to be possible, there must have been a breach in the defenses.
The weak part are services configured for
[constrained delegations](https://www.thehacker.recipes/ad/movement/kerberos/delegations/constrained)
where the service class can be modified in the ticket,
allowing attackers to have access to other types of services.

For more information, see
[Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://www.ired.team/offensive-security-experiments/active-directory-kerberos-abuse/abusing-kerberos-constrained-delegation).